# Show a previous page value in Drupal multi-step webform?

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

In [a multi-step Drupal webform](http://drupal.org/node/324779), is it possible to show a value entered in a previous-step page?

For example, the first step page captures a `username` field as "John", is it possible to show a greeting in next step page, showing `Hello John, ...` ?

p.s. for anonymous user.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I needed the same thing so I hope this helps others in search.

I needed values from a previous Webform step for my custom Webform component. The `_webform_redner_[component](...)` hook doesn't provide the `form` or `form_state`, also the previous steps' data (more than previous step that was just submitted) isn't in the `$_POST`.

To solve this, I manually retrieve the form from Drupal's form caching system using the `form_build_id` which is in the `$_POST` variable.

```php
  /* ... */
  $form_state = array();
  // Get the form_state to pass on to our build function.
  // Webforms doesn't provide it at this point so we'll need to manually get it using the form's build_id.
  $form = form_get_cache($_POST['form_build_id'], $form_state); 
  /* ... */
```

You now have the entire `form` and `form_state` that also includes previous steps' values.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at multistep form example here: http://drupal.org/node/717750

The general idea is that in the submit function you save all posted values to `$form_state['storage']`, which you can later access on the next steps.

Edit:
Have a look at the example with both Prev and Next buttons I have just created: http://zgadzaj.com/basic-drupal-multipart-form-example-with-previous-and-next-buttons

Comment: Is there a way for doing this in Webform (http://drupal.org/project/webform), instead of via Form API?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid, I'm not using it at all. I guess there would be a way, not sure how much altering would it need, and if it would be really better in terms of amount of time/work required...